# UIImageView Leak / Autorelease

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am running a fairly memory intensive loop to generate images and have come unstuck in memory leaks / the autorelease retaining memory allocations for too long.

Can anyone please explain exactly what is being held and autoreleased below? I have run this through the Allocations instrument and it increases in size until the loop finishes and deallocates all of the autorelease objects (as I understand it from 3 days of trial and error). This is ok for less loops but when I exceed 200 it eventually crashes before it gets to autorelease. By commenting out the following code, this increase stops and the Instruments graph stays horizontal with a set amount of memory:

```
   for (int l=0;1 < 300; 1++) {
      UIImage * Img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:Path]; //Path is a NSString pointing to bundlePath and a sample image
      UIImageView *ImgCont = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Img];

      //here I usually add the view to a UIView but it is not required to see the problem
      ImgCont.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

      [ImgCont release];
      [Img release];
   }
```

I have tried wrapping this with a NSAutoreleasePool without success - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

When you add the imageView to a view, it's retained by that view, so even if you release Img and ImgCont, they still exist, and you are left with 300 objects.

Also, and I'm not completely sure about this, but if you are using the same image over and over, you should use [UIImage imageNamed:NAME], since it reuses the images, something I can not say for [UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:PATH]; (If the OS doesn't optimize that case, right now you have the same image 300 times in the memory).

Comment: That makes sense. Is it possible forcefully release the image held within the UIImageView and not wait for the autorelease? Presume it is not as simple as [UIImageView.Image release]?   With your second comment, I am using the same image for this example trying to track down where it is not being released as I have a separate function that is returning the image in the full app. Changing the code to imageNamed has improved it but it is still slowly increasing.

Comment: Nowhere in your code an image is being autoreleased, so I'm not sure what you mean by that. The thing is, if you want to use an object, it HAS to be in memory, so if you manage to dealloc the image inside an imageView, your app will crash. What you can do to keep the performance and memory low is to skip the UIImageView and write your own subclass of UIView that overrides drawRect: and draws the same image several times.

Comment: I know and it has baffled me for about a week. As per the links I gave matt, with the exact code as I have attached included something is definitely being released as the loop finishes. If I comment this code out, it is fine and doesn't increase. I like the sound of your suggestion. Would you have a link or direction so I can investigate further?

Answer (score 1):

None of the objects you are explicitly creating are being autoreleased so it must be stuff inside those UIKit calls you have. There's not a lot you can do about that though in terms of cutting down the number of autoreleases. But what you can do is mess around with autorelease pools.

You say you've tried `NSAutoreleasePool` but have you tried wrapping each iteration of the loop in a pool like so:

```
for (int l=0;1 < 300; 1++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage * Img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:Path]; //Path is a NSString pointing to bundlePath and a sample image
        UIImageView *ImgCont = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Img];

        //here I usually add the view to a UIView but it is not required to see the problem
        ImgCont.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

        [ImgCont release];
        [Img release];
    }
```

}

Although you should think about not doing it exactly like that, because it's possibly overkill. But I suggest you try that and if you're still having problems, then it's not this loop.

Comment: That is what I thought. It has been driving me mental for about a week working top down and now bottom up to see where the memory is going. So is there some chance that instruments is just playing tricks? This here is the Instruments Allocations with the exact above code included: http://i49.tinypic.com/296dhsg.jpg and here is the one with the exact above code removed: http://i48.tinypic.com/296n7lt.png

Comment: So does wrapping the inner part of the loop in an autorelease pool not help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Seems to have a slight improvement but it is still increasing slowly and once the loop is complete, drops back as seen in the first link. Which is what was making me think it was an Autorelease but comments seem to be pointing elsewhere

Comment: Yeh that looks odd. It might be something inside UIKit, but does sound slightly odd.